# Creating matplotlib plots raises RunTimeError in my tk GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

**TLDR**: I can't save my graphs from `matplotlib` without my `tkinter` GUI acting up even though my GUI is running in the main thread and the `matplotlib` functions are called within a separate thread.

---

I am trying to make graphs in python. I am using `matplotlib`. I have successfully plotted my first graph however, the problem I'm facing seems to be related my GUI that is written in `tkinter`. I am using Python3.

In short, my code reads binary files and makes a graph for each binary file. So in my function `read_files`, which when run is its own thread, I have a for loop of reading the binary file and creating a plot and saving the plot.

Upon running my script, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 911, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 859, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\PurgePressureAnalysis\GUI.py", line 77, in callback
    self.function_chain_v1()
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\PurgePressureAnalysis\GUI.py", line 101, in function_chain_v1
    (func.__func__)(self.infoObj)
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\PurgePressureAnalysis\lib\features.py", line 96, in waveform_analysis
    Graph.plot_lt_wvfrm(case_wvfrm)
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\PurgePressureAnalysis\lib\graph.py", line 18, in plot_lt_wvfrm
    fig = plt.figure()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 527, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 84, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 101, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    icon_img = Tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_fname)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3421, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3377, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444972/why-matplotlib-requires-to-plot-only-in-the-main-thread), I know that the problem is related to `tkinter` and not `matplotlib`. I have confirmed this because I successfully saved my plot before the error was thrown.

Here are the relevant parts of my code (some parts are cut out for simplification):

This is the function called when I click on a button in my GUI.

```
def Search(self):
    def callback():
        try:
            self.function_chain_v1()
            self.add_text('Search Complete')
        except OSError as e:
            handle_exceptions()

    self.t = threading.Thread(target = callback)
    self.t.start()
```

This function calls my plot and save function. This function is called in Thread-1. (some parts have been cut out for simplicity):

```
@staticmethod
def waveform_analysis(infoObj):
    for case in infoObj.filelist:
        wvfrm_per_case = []
        case_wvfrm = []
        for index in range(len(case)):
            case_wvfrm = read_binary() #simplification of what is really happening
        Convert.convert_wvfrm_to_csv(case_wvfrm, a)
        Graph.plot_lt_wvfrm(case_wvfrm)

    return infoObj.output
```

And this is the plot function This function is called in Thread-1.:

```
@staticmethod
    def plot_lt_wvfrm(wvfrms):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (0,0), rowspan = 1)
        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (1,0), rowspan = 1)

        x, y = read(channel_y, purge_y, wvfrms)
        for ys in y:
            ax1.plot(x, ys)

        x, y = read(purge_y, len(wvfrms[0]), wvfrms)
        for ys in y:
            ax2.plot(x, ys)

        plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\dzhao\\Desktop\\' + str(wvfrms[0][1]) + '.png')
```

What I've tried:

I've tried putting this `Graph.plot_lt_wvfrm` into another thread (so a thread within a thread) and the .png file was successfully saved but this error related to `tkinter` still occurs. I've looked into Queues from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989446/execute-python-function-in-main-thread-from-call-in-dummy-thread) but I'm hesitant to try this because I'm not sure if queues will solve the root cause of this error. I've also tried moving some of the functions related to `matplotlib` into the main thread (like `fig = plt.figure()) but this didn't do anything.

All I know is that this is a thread related issue because `matplotlib` also uses `tkinter` and somewhere they're fighting over something.

Yeah... you can tell my understanding of this problem by how vague my analysis is.

How do I keep my GUI working (preventing this `RunTimeError` from appearing) but also have my graph making + saving function work?

Other questions I've looked at: [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351488/intermittent-python-thread-error-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop) [context2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016102/matplotlib-and-multiprocessing-runtimeerror) [context3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556479/running-a-tkinter-form-in-a-separate-thread) [context 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop)

Comment: You may need to change the backend for matplotlib, i.e. `import matplotlib` followed by `matplotlib.use('Agg')`

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Thanks for the tip I'm looking into it. But... Could you explain to me what the general meaning of 'back end' means? What is the big picture?